# How to clean bathroom floor marble without using hard chemicals?

Tags: cleaning

What advice can I give to my 60 year old mother to easily clean white marble floor in the bathroom. I do not want her to deal with hard chemicals or too much scrubbing. She cannot use a house maid/help due to unavailability in her locality.

Answer (score 1):

Marble Floors

For marble flooring, the Marble Institute advises dust-mopping floors frequently and cleaning with a mild, phosphate-free biodegradable liquid dishwashing soap or powder, or a stone soap. Soapless cleaners minimize streaks and film. After washing, rinse with clean water and dry.

The MIA also cautions against using cleaners that contain acid, such as bathroom cleaners, grout cleaners, and tub and tile cleaners, which can cause etching. And don’t use bleach. If you bleach it, it will break the shine down. Stick to soap and water.”

In addition, avoid using old vacuums, because metal attachments and well-worn wheels may scratch the surface.

Answer (score 0):

### Wet Baking Soda

I have had to clean white bathtubs before where the stains were so hard to remove that even oven cleaner would not clean away the dirt. There, I tried leaving a layer of wet baking soda all over the stained areas. After a few hours, the stains and dirt just wiped off without any scrubbing.

[image]